# How To Check Whether My Tensorflow Code is Correct?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Following is the network structure from the [Deep Video Portrait (2018)](https://web.stanford.edu/~zollhoef/papers/SG2018_DeepVideo/page.html)

[image: Deep Video Portrait]
[image: explanation]

With a reference to the above explanation, I'd written down a code as following :

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# hyper-params 
learning_rate = 0.0002
epochs = 250
batch_size = 16
N_w = 11 #number of frames concatenated together 
channels = 9*N_w
drop_out = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# input_tensor X  
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 256, 256, channels]) # batch_size x Height x Width x N_w 

def conv_down(x, N, stride, count): #Conv [4x4, str_2] > Batch_Normalization > Leaky_ReLU
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_down_{}_{}".format(N, count)) : #N == depth of tensor 
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_down_4x4_str{}".format(stride)) : #this's used for downsampling
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=stride, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x) 
            x = tf.nn.relu(x) #change it into leaky_relu in version 1.8 : now in 1.1
    return x

def conv_up(x, N, drop_rate, stride, count): #Conv_transpose [4x4, str_2] > Batch_Normalizaiton > DropOut > ReLU
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_up_{}_{}".format(N, count)) : #N == depth of tensor
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_up_4x4_str{}".format(stride)) :
            x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, N, kernel_size=4, strides=stride, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
            if drop_rate is not 0:
                x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x

def conv_refine1(x, N, drop_rate, count): #Conv [3x3, str_1] > Batch_Normalization > DropOut > ReLU
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_refine_1_{}_{}".format(N, count)) :
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_refine_3x3_str1") :
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
            if drop_rate is not 0:
                x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x 

def conv_refine2(x, N, drop_rate, count): #Conv [3x3, str_1] > Batch_Normalization > DropOut > ReLU
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_refine_2_{}_{}".format(N, count)) :
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_refine_3x3_str1") :
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, N, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(0.2)))
            x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x)
            if drop_rate is not 0:
                x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=drop_rate)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x    

def conv_upsample(x, N, drop_rate, stride, count):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv_upsamp_{}_{}".format(N,count)) :
        x = conv_up(x, 2*N, drop_rate, stride, count)
        x = conv_refine1(x, N, drop_rate, count)
        x = conv_refine2(x, N, drop_rate, count)
    return x 

def biLinearDown(x, N):
    return tf.image.resize_images(x, [N, N])

def finalTanH(x):
    return tf.nn.tanh(x)

def T(x):

    #channel_output_structure
    down_channel_output = [64, 128, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
    up_channel_output= [512, 512, 512, 512, 256, 128, 64, 3]
    biLinearDown_output= [32, 64, 128] #for skip-connection 

    #down_sampling
    conv1 = conv_down(x, down_channel_output[0], 2, 1)
    conv2 = conv_down(conv1, down_channel_output[1], 2, 2)
    conv3 = conv_down(conv2, down_channel_output[2], 2, 3)
    conv4 = conv_down(conv3, down_channel_output[3], 1, 4)
    conv5 = conv_down(conv4, down_channel_output[4], 1, 5)
    conv6 = conv_down(conv5, down_channel_output[5], 1, 6)
    conv7 = conv_down(conv6, down_channel_output[6], 1, 7)
    conv8 = conv_down(conv7, down_channel_output[7], 1, 8)

    #upsampling 
    dconv1 = conv_upsample(conv8, up_channel_output[0], drop_out[0], 1, 1)
    dconv2 = conv_upsample(dconv1, up_channel_output[1], drop_out[1], 1, 2)
    dconv3 = conv_upsample(dconv2, up_channel_output[2], drop_out[2], 1, 3)
    dconv4 = conv_upsample(dconv3, up_channel_output[3], drop_out[3], 1, 4)
    dconv5 = conv_upsample(dconv3, up_channel_output[4], drop_out[4], 1, 5)
    dconv6 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv5, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[0])], axis=3), up_channel_output[5], drop_out[5], 2, 6)
    dconv7 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv6, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[1])], axis=3), up_channel_output[6], drop_out[6], 2, 7)
    dconv8 = conv_upsample(tf.concat([dconv7, biLinearDown(x, biLinearDown_output[2])], axis=3), up_channel_output[7], drop_out[7], 2, 8)

    #final_tanh
    T_x = finalTanH(dconv8)

    return T_x

sheudo_np = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=[16, 256,256, 11])

sheudo_input = tf.Variable(np.float32(sheudo_np))

T_x = T(sheudo_input)
```

The last variable `T_x` has a shape of `(16, 256, 256, 3)` so I think the dimension is okay. How could I check further not just dimension but whether the network structure is well coded?

Is there any practitioner's guide for use of tensorflow for deep learning?

Comment: Use Tensorflow Debugger. It shows values and shapes of all the tensors. Allows you to step through the graph. Finally, has nice nan catching filters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - welcome to the world of tensorflow, where everything is blacked box away from you and you have very little insight into whether it's actually doing what you want it to do. I think this is consistently a large gripe with the platform, and one which does not have stellar work-arounds. Nonetheless, here is a non-exhaustive list of options for figuring out what's going on in your network's guts.

- Call sess.run on all of the variables that you are interested in seeing.

  - This will print out the tensors flowing through your net as numpy arrays that are easily printable and legible.
- Create tensorboard plots for *everything* that you are interested in observing.

  - I recommend putting every loss into a tensorboard plot, the gradients into a tensorboard plot, the sum of the weights into a tensorboard plot (if not per layer then at least for the entire network). These will show you the progression of any object of interest over the course of training. I'd argue that it is invaluable information for providing insight into what's going on under the hood.
- Tensorflow's eager mode execution allows you to see the values going through the graph in real time.

  - I will concede that I haven't worked with it yet, since there are so many tf APIs that I've been trying to learn that I simply haven't had the chance yet. From what I understand, it works fairly well but is somewhat limited. Wish I could offer more on that, but it is what it is.
- Lastly, I like to make simple test scripts to double check that all of my reshaping/tiling/concatenating operations are doing *exactly* what I expect them to be doing.

  - This means creating a simple script like:

    - `A = tf.constant([1, 2], [3, 4]); B = tf.reshape(A, [-1]); sess = tf.Session(); print(sess.run(B));`
  - This is a pretty trivial example, but you see what I mean. Sometimes the transposing + tiling + reshaping + everything_else-ing will come out differently than you expect, so this is an easy way to double check that you have the correct operations in your graph.

Happy debugging!